# How can you use Firebase rules to allow user and admin write privileges?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase rules to set permissions and I am having trouble setting up rule to allow write permissions to include the user and any admin.

Below is the database I am trying to set permissions for:

```
'rules': {
    'rankings': { 
        'user': {
            'userShortenedAuthId': { //user's rankings },
            'anotherShortenedAuthId': { //another user's rankings }
        }
    },
    'admin': {
        'adminAuthId': true
    },
    'users': {
        'userAuthId': {
            'rank': 'userShortenedAuthId'
        },
        'anotherAuthId': {
            'rank': 'anotherShortenedAuthId'
        }
    }
}
```

These are the rules in place for this data:

```
"rankings":{
    "user":{
        "$rankId": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth != null && ((root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/rank').val() == $rankId) || root.child('admin/' + auth.uid).exists())"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write to a 'rankings/user/userShortenedId' while logged in under the admin, but I get a permission denied error from Firebase. (Logged in as the user works just fine). The error is somewhere in the 'rankings/user/$rankId/.write' rule. What is confusing for me, is I have been using the 'root.child('admin/' + auth.uid).exists())' rule elsewhere for admin privileges and that seems to work fine too.

Here is the code that produces the permission error.

```
firebase.database().ref('rankings/' + userShortenedAuthId).update({newPlayerKey:totalPlayers}))
    .then(function(){
        console.log('successfully updated user ranking');
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('error updated user ranking', err);
    });
```

Comment: You're missing a top-level `"rules"` node. Is that one present in your real rules (and just missing from the snippet you posted)? Also: can you show the minimal code that reproduces the write failure?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The top level 'rules' is in place, just not included here. I'll add in, above, the code that produced the failure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen NVM! I realized I am trying to reach the wrong firebase ref URL. It should be 'rankings/user/' + userShortenedAuthId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. The firebase ref URL that was referenced when trying to update

`firebase.database().ref('rankings/' + userShortenedAuthId).update({newPlayerKey:totalPlayers}))`

should actually be

`firebase.database().ref('rankings/user/' + userShortenedAuthId).update({newPlayerKey:totalPlayers}))`

So the rules were actually working correctly. I was simply trying to write to the wrong place.